# Debezium: Mysql LONGTEXT to Debezium Data type conversions is not correct

Tags: debezium

### mysql schema

```sql
 `Info` longtext,
```

### debezium schema for the same field

```json
{
     "name": "Info",
      "type": [
          "null",
          "string"
       ],
      "default": null
},
```

When this data is loaded in Redshift it fails as it expects the data type to be large i.e. `VARCHAR(MAX)` but it is getting `VARCHAR(255)` since debezium is not transforming longtext to long.

Please suggest, why is this happening.

Answer (score 1):

please take a look at https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.2/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-property-column-propagate-source-type

This will add the type constarint parameters into the schema.

Also IIUC you are using Confluent Avro Converter. If yes then set `enhanced.avro.schema.support` and `connect.meta.data` to `true`.

In this case you will need to convert the Debezium onstraint params into ones supported by the sink converter if such functionlaity is provided.

Comment: Thank you once again, checking.

Comment: Please point to the documentation for avro schema configs also. Wanted to know why are the avro schema support flag and connect meta data are requierd?